# ssllab generate tons of handshake exception

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, elastic-load-balancer, internal-load-balancer

I'm using SSL Labs to test the certificate for the website and it will generate tons of handshake exceptions in my debug log. The exception is showing below:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:928)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
at bri.web.WebResponse.getMoreData(WebResponse.java:465)
at bri.web.WebResponse.parseRequest(WebResponse.java:362)
at bri.web.WebResponse.processRequest(WebResponse.java:99)
at bri.web.WebResponse.run(WebResponse.java:56)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
    ... 12 more
```

I tried so many ways to fix this but it won't help:

```
  1. I added -Dhttps.protocols="TLSv1.0,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" when I'm running Java
  2. All certificates are installed correctly based on the reports from SSL labs
```

As far as I am concerned, I think that SSL Lab is sending requests that includes nothing for testing the connection to the website. And since our web server is customized, it doesn't have the ability to deal with empty request. What our server will do to deal with requests is in following code:

```
// RESET CONNECTION VARIABLES
    REQUEST        = new HashMap();
    RESOURCE       = "";
    QUERY_STRING   = "";
    METHOD         = "";
    PROTOCOL       = "";
    HOST           = "";
    CONTENT_TYPE   = "";
    CONTENT_LENGTH = 0;
    USER_AGENT     = "";
    ETAG           = "";
    CONNECTION     = "";
    REFERER        = "";
    FORM_ELEMENTS  = "";
    IP             = "";
    REDIRECT       = false;
    bypassed       = false;
    length         = 0;
    totalLength    = -1;
    blankCount     = 0;
    name           = "";
    value          = "";

    // BLOCK AND WAIT FOR A CONNECTION
    socket = w.getConnection();

    //BriDebug.debug("WebResponse " + this.getName() + " is processing");

    IP = socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
    out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(), w.CHARSET);
    parseRequest();
```

And when we are using isr (InputStreamReader) to read the inputstream from socket, the exception will happen and the handshake exception will pop out. And the tricky thing is that in this way, our system is working correctly. If users are accessing to our website, the requests sent to server have information and parseRequest() will help decrypt the request and help users get to correct pages.

Can anybody help me with this? And does anyone know how I can deal with empty requests send from others? (In fact, we are using load balancer and when load balancer is sending empty requests to our server to check the connection, same exception would happen as well.) And does anyone know if I want to hard code the respond that needed to be sent back to others (i.e SSL Labs, Load balancer), what should them look like?

Any help is appreciated. Happy Holiday guys.

Comment: I want to add 1 more thing here. The exception is happening this line:      length = isr.read(header);     And this line will lead me directly to handshake exception. Remember, isr is the inputstreamreader and I'm trying to read the socket inputstream into a char array 'header'. 'header' is initialized with length 1024.